# Configuring Jenkins as a Windows Service: JENKINS_HOME, Path, & file structure

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, windows-services

I want to learn about CI & Jenkins so I DL & installed Jenkins on my machine(*Windows 10, 64x*).  I proceed with configuring Jenkins as a Windows Service.

I followed this tutorial:

http://yakiloo.com/setup-jenkins-and-windows/

Below, I have detailed how I proceeded with my setup.  My concern is I may have made some mistakes during setup.  These concern are provided below, followed with my questions.

### Steps Taken during setup:

I DL Jenkins Long-Term Support Release.

Created:

*C:\jenkins\.jenkins*

Moved *jenkins.war* to:

*C:\jenkins\.jenkins*

**HERE IS WHERE I THINK I WENT WRONG.**

Created system variable:

*JENKINS_HOME*

With a value of:

*C:\jenkins*

**I THINK I SHOULD HAVE PROVIDED A VALUE OF:**

*C:\jenkins\.jenkins*

I edited my Path value with:

*%JENKINS_HOME%\.jenkins*

I then issued the following command from cmd:

*java -jar jenkins.war*

This DL & installed files.

I opened Jenkin from:

*localhost:8080/*

Proceed with installing as Windows Service.

For my installation directory I was prompted with the value of *JENKINS_HOME*:

*C:\jenkins*

Select “*Install*”.

Installation Complete, selected "*Yes*" to stop & start newly installed windows service.

This all worked correctly.  Jenkins is installed as a windows service, I can start & stop from Windows services.

**MY CONCERN IS MY FILE STRUCTURE LOOKS LIKE THIS**:

http://screencast.com/t/07wLvwm4Lo

Where I would think I would want the files located in:

*C:\jenkins*

To be located in:

*C:\jenkins\.jenkins*

### Questions

**QUESTION:** Am I right in thinking this? Or does it not matter?  Jenkins seems to be working fine, but I would prefer to have it setup/configured properly/the standard way on my machine.

**QUESTION:** If Jenkins is not setup/configured properly/the standard way on my machine how would/should I change this(keeping in mind I have in configured as a Windows service)?

**QUESTION:** If needed, how should I amend the values of JENKIN_HOME & Path?

**QUESTION:** In short, is my setup right or wrong?  If wrong, should I change?  If so, how?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Jenkins service is running then you are past the first speed bump.  Honestly where the core Jenkins files are saved is inconsequential as you will be defining all of your project aspects through your Jenkins jobs.  Your next step should definitely be to focus on creating a job, hooking it up to a repository, and getting it to build correctly.